# How to communicate between Actionscript 3 And ASp.NET?

Tags: asp.net, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

i would like to know how to communicate between a flash project and an asp server.My purpose is that load machine generated xml file to flash.I know oly to communicate between xml file and flash.Any one have solution?

Comment: When you're talking communication, are you just looking for requests?  Or the ability to run full scripts, data calls, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it can be done with **urlvariables** and with post method

```
var scriptRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("Default.aspx");
  var scriptLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
  var scriptVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
  scriptLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, handleLoadSuccessful);
  scriptLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, handleLoadError);
  scriptVars.var1 = "one";
  scriptRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
  scriptRequest.data = scriptVars;
  scriptLoader.load(scriptRequest);

  function handleLoadSuccessful($evt:Event):void {
   txt.text="sent";
   trace("Message sent.");
  }

  function handleLoadError($evt:IOErrorEvent):void {
    txt.text="failed";
    trace("Message failed.")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use flash remoting. It allows a flash application to call an asp.net service (method) using remoting connection.

You will need FluorineFX or WebORB on the server side